# Пропущена запятая в тесте?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, егэ

Смутило отсутствие запятой в демонстрационном варианте ЕГЭ.

*Навстречу(,) медленно, тяжело громыхая, двигался гружёный состав, а вдали тянулся ещё один.*

Нужна она здесь? Спасибо!

Comment: Запятая, конечно же, не нужна, вам неправильно ответили.

Comment: _Ормонд: «Пропущена запятая **в тесте**»_? 

Comment: @slava1947: про тест Римма добавила. :)

Comment: @slava1947 Слава, я понимаю, что можно и поудивляться, и посмеяться (тесто — в тесте; тест — в тесте). Может, исправить? *Пропущена запятая в предложении.* Мне-то хотелось обозначить, что это именно из теста (вот, опять!) ЕГЭ. *Пропущена запятая в тексте ЕГЭ*? Посоветуйте, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот, собственно, предлагаемый [**вариант ЕГЭ**](https://teletype.in/@rus_dil/14Demo22):
14. Определите предложение, в котором оба выделенных слова пишутся СЛИТНО.
3) (НА)ВСТРЕЧУ медленно, тяжело громыхая, двигался гружёный состав, а (В)ДАЛИ тянулся ещё один.

Нет проблем именно с этим (со слитным написанием): **навстречу, вдали**.

А вот пунктуация тут может быть всякой.

1. Навстречу медленно, тяжело громыхая, двигался гружёный состав, а вдали тянулся ещё один.
2. Навстречу медленно, тяжело, громыхая, двигался гружёный состав...
3. Навстречу — медленно, тяжело громыхая, — двигался гружёный состав...
4. Навстречу — медленно, тяжело, громыхая, — двигался гружёный состав...

Ваши смущения напрасны. Всякой может быть пунктуация — авторство ведь не указано (посмотреть, сравнить, заценить — негде). Но запятой после "навстречу", считаю, быть никак не должно.

Из Нацкорпуса:
Навстречу медленно, слепя фарами, наезжал джип, осторожно причаливал к тротуару. [Александр Проханов. Господин Гексоген (2001)]

Comment: Спасибо! А "медленно,тяжело громыхая" не будет деепричастным оборотом, который надо обособить?

Comment: ‟ Медленно ” относится к ‟ двигался ”, а не к ‟ громыхая ”. Нельзя громыхать медленно.

Comment: @Ормонд *Медленно* — отдельно, *тяжело громыхая* — отдельно. И всё уже обособлено. Разве нет?

Comment: Римма, вы неправы в конце! После *д**о**лжно,* на мой взгляд, может быть только активный глагол.

Comment: М-м... Не согласна с вами (я помню, мы договорились просто на "вы". Да, думаю, можно уже и на "ты", если не против?). Никак не до́лжно = никак не нужно. Можно здесь посмотреть (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE).

Comment: Я совсем не против, спасибо за предложение!) Мне кажется, что самая близкая замена *следует.* То есть получается так: "запятой находиться там никак не следует". Не привык, чтобы с *до́лжно* употребляли статичные глаголы. Может, вопрос отдельный создадим?

Comment: Что-то Alex_ander давно не заходил... :((

Comment: Римма, ждал ответа на комментарий, не дождался. :(

Comment: Уже поздно было, Артём. Да, похоже, что я подзапуталась с ударением. "Щаз" поправлю. И да: ты прав, *Alex_ander* давно не заходил (посмотрела — больше месяца).

Comment: Давай сразу договоримся: можно к тебе обращаться *Рим* или тебе не нравится такая форма? =) Задавал уже довольно давно вопрос про подобные имена, упоминал там как примеры Аллу и Инну и в голове держал, что у нас есть тут и Римма Михайлова. :)))

Comment: Надеюсь, ничем не обидел? Жду ответа. ;)

Comment: Вообще непонятно: то дожидаешься ответа, то нет...

Comment: Иногда комментарии приходят с большим опозданием. Конечно же, Артём, не против (я почти привыкла к этому имени). Настоящее можно посмотреть на Мете (итоги 2017 года).

Comment: Очень интересно! Спасибо, не видел тех Итогов!

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, другие вам ответят гораздо лучше, но я скажу, что ***запятая не нужна,*** потому что наречия *навстречу* и *медленно* характеризуют процесс совершенно с разных сторон и вовсе не являются однородными членами. Запятой я бы и в страшном сне тут не помыслил!

Answer (score 0):

Да, нужна, так как наречия характеристики действия обособляются, если оторваны от слова, к которому они относятся. Вот несколько примеров из [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=115#pp115):
Иногда он обращался с какой-нибудь просьбой, робко, застенчиво (Кат.).
Он, молча, опять поклонился (Л.).

Comment: _Jim Korbett: Да, нужна…_ === Нужна??? Ав этом предложении Вы тоже поставили бы запятую: _**Навстречу медленно двигался гружёный состав**_?

Comment: Нет, потому что здесь наречие характеристики действия ‟ медленно ” не оторвано от слова, к которому оно относится. Наречия характеристики действия относятся к глаголу, если что.